# How facebook auto detect the post and comment id?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I was playing with [facebook graph api](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/), where I wanted to get the posts by me and it's related comments.
I get all posts of using `me/posts/` and the `id` of each post is appended with the `user-id` i.e if my `user-id` is `1234` then the list of post would be like (JSON):

```
{    
 id:1234_50    
}    
{    
 id:1234_51    
}   
{    
 id:1234_53    
}
```

And now if I copy the `post-id` and paste it to `facebook.com/1234_53` then it redirects me to that post. Ok that's fine, facebook identifies that the left part of `_` is `user-id` and right is `post-id`.
But when I dive some more deeper and query the api for the comments of posts using `<post-id>/comments`, it returns me the metadata for comments. Again each comment has a unique id. Suppose `post 53` has a comment having `id= 777`. So the JSON returned for that is `id:53_777`. Now when I append this to `facebook.com/53_777`, this time api identify the left part of `_` as the post id and the right part as the comment id.
I am curious to know how api working differently in above scenarios?
*NOTE: I am thinking all this in an RDBMS perspective where user, posts and comments must be having separate tables*

Answer (score 0):

you can use :
me/posts/?fields=comments{id}